# Can't update node value in tree

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I'm encountering this weird bug were I can't update a value in a tree. Let me explain :
I have this "PlanetChunk" tree struct (simplified) :

```cs
public struct PlanetChunk
{
    public PlanetChunk[] children;
    public bool isLeaf;
    private int meshStartIndex;
    private int meshLength;

    public void OffsetMeshStartIndexRec(int threshold, int offset)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"BEFORE : start : {meshStartIndex}, length : {meshLength}");

        if(meshStartIndex > threshold)
        {
            meshStartIndex += offset;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"AFTER : start : {meshStartIndex}, length : {meshLength}");

        if(!isLeaf)
        {
            foreach(PlanetChunk child in children)
            {
                children.OffsetMeshStartIndexRec(threshold, offset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the recursive method seems to be changing my startMeshIndex, but doesn't.
In this exemple, I have one root planetChunk that contains 8 children, all of them are leaves.

When I execute this code :

```cs
root.OffsetMeshStartIndexRecursive(0, 1);
Console.WriteLine($"AFTER EXEC : {root.children[7].meshStartIndex}");
```

This is the console output :

[image: Console output]

(Note that i have code that first, generates the planetChunks and set the values)

The first two lines are from the root PlanetChunk, startIndex is 0 so there are no changes,
3rd and 4th lines are from first child, startIndex is 0 so there are no changes.

Then for every other children, we can see that the meshStartIndex is indeed updated.

But when the recursive method finish, and i ask the last child what is his meshStartIndex, it hasn't changed.

Anyone would know why this would occurs ?

Comment: Change PlanetChunk from struct to class and see what happens.

Comment: @Ralf This actually works. Could I have any explainations why ? And wouldn't it be better to use structs here ?

Comment: structs are valuetypes. You might want to read on the differences between valuetypes and referencetypes. Valuetypes means when assigning you get a copy of the value. Here it happens in your foreach. Child will be a copy of the object in children.

Comment: And no struct is not better here. A mutable struct is in almost all cases a dead end. It will get you into trouble.

Comment: So when I use the foreach loop, it actually copies all the children and call the method on the copy ?
Anyway, thanks for the help !

Comment: You are correct.